# Xamarin.Forms - How to work out valid XAML syntax from API Documentation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I use the API Documentation to work out what is valid XAML for each Xamarin.Forms 
Control.

For example, for a Label Control I think I can see which attributes I can set on it by looking at its available **Properties** List - http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.Label%2fP

But for something like a RelativeLayout (http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout) which only has a Children property, how do I set up things like that shown in the code to control its childrens constraints and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give up on this effort right now.

Instead find the source code of Xamarin.Forms by right-clicking on a class name in your code and selecting "Go to Declaration" - you can see all the source code from Xamarin.Forms and many other libraries.

Code doesn't lie, documentation - not so sure :)

If you do that on `Label` you see its Bindable Properties right on top of the class, including their type. Now look at the `FontProperty` - in the type parameters there's a reference to the `Font` class - click it. The class has a `[TypeConverter(typeof(FontTypeConverter))]` attribute. Click the `FontTypeConverter` and see how it works.

After a bit of practice you may find it very useful to know what the code actually does, regardless what the documentation says or doesn't say

---

If you're looking to understand XAML start by looking at one of the many WPF or Silverlight tutorials online to get a grip on how it works - the concept is the same and the technologies have been around much longer, resources are plentiful.

A rough sketch on how XAML works:

You have classes created in .NET and possibly marked with some attributes. XAML allows you to deserialize a complex structure from XML.

Each XML element maps to a class type. Each XML attribute maps to a property of that class. Some properties are easy to fit in an attribute (see the Font example above, Color is another); properties that are themselves structures can be defined inside a child XML element named , such as:

```
<Label Text="this is a label">
  <Label.Font>
   <Font....>
  </Label.Font>
</Label>
```

There are several important concepts related to XAML, such as:

- [BindlableObject](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.BindableObject) which is allows property values to be bound to one-another, so when one changes the other changes too
- [Markup Extensions](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/xaml_markup_extensions/) allow you to express things in XAML, such as referring to a Resource or creating a Binding
- Type Converters can convert between value types and allow thing such as using the name of a color or biding `int` to `string` properties

Comment: Thanks, I do agree that it would be very useful to understand the source code, especially in the lack of documentation (but obviously extremely time consuming if you just want to know how to layout a few children for a layout!).  Maybe I should change the question to how to create the XAML from looking at the code? If no better suggestions will mark as answer and see if I can decipher it as I learn more about XAML / Forms.

Comment: updated answer, does it make more sense how the code ties in to the XML of XAML?

Comment: Thanks, will look into XAML concepts more as you suggest.

Comment: This is a good resource for looking at the concepts @Sten discusses above - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189036%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using VS, but there is no intellisense with the xaml, I use Xamarin Studio to do the XAML only as there is auto-completion there.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I was using XS, but even that intellisense was not 100% helpful, will revisit XF on future releases.